# Windows Phone 8: Code for Getting directions running in Emulator but throwing exception in Device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, event-handling, windows-phone

I have been writing a snippet to get direction between two GeoCoordinates in Windows Phone 8. That particular code is running fine in Emaulator but when I deployed and tested it in Device it is throwing `'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'`  . In my appmanifest ID_CAP_MAP and ID_CAP_LOCATION is enabled. Below is the code snippet that I am using

```
private void RequestDirections()
        {
            rq.QueryCompleted += routeQuery_QueryCompleted;

            if (!rq.IsBusy)
            {
                List<GeoCoordinate> routeCoordinates = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
                routeCoordinates.Add(new GeoCoordinate(48.860339, 2.337599));
                routeCoordinates.Add(new GeoCoordinate(48.8583, 2.2945));

                rq.Waypoints = routeCoordinates;
                rq.QueryAsync();

                map.Center = new GeoCoordinate(48.8583, 2.2945); //Center map on last coordinates
            }
        }

        private void routeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    Route theRoute = e.Result;
                    MapRoute calculatedMapRoute = new MapRoute(theRoute);
                    map.ZoomLevel = 17;
                    map.AddRoute(calculatedMapRoute);

                    //Used Only For Direction List Button

                    sb.AppendLine("Distance to destination: " + e.Result.LengthInMeters);
                    sb.AppendLine("Time to destination: " + e.Result.EstimatedDuration);
                    foreach (var maneuver in e.Result.Legs.SelectMany(l => l.Maneuvers))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("At " + maneuver.StartGeoCoordinate + " " +
                                                maneuver.InstructionKind + ": " +
                                                maneuver.InstructionText + " for " +
                                                maneuver.LengthInMeters + " meters");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

And the error I am getting is in `routeQuery_QueryCompleted` method. The `QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e` is thrown as null. Exact error `"'e.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'"`

It would be great if anybody could suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you sure you have the maps installed for those coordinates?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml yes it is installed. I used an alternate code.

 Uri uri = new Uri("ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=" + latitude +
                "&destination.longitude=" + longitude + "&destination.name=" + name); This launches the Direction App for Win Phone.

Answer (score 0):

TargetInvocation just means that something was calling reflection Invoke, and the invoked method threw an exception. The real problem is hiding in the .InnerException. So you should catch the exception and inspect the .InnerException to see what is actually going wrong. Also look at the .StackTrace. of the .InnerException to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I'm unable to comment as i don't have much reputation, sorry...that;s why i had to put it as an answer...I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GeoCoordinateWatcher`.

The Windows Phone API has a `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class which fires a `PositionChanged` event which can be used to track the user’s location. It is very easy to render the user’s movements on a map via a `MapPolyLine`, which is a line path which is defined in terms of `geocoordinates`.

[This](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/A_Windows_Phone_8_Run_Tracking_App_in_100_Lines_of_Code!) article explains how to create a run-tracker app using Windows Phone 8

Comment: Thanks for the input..I will try to implement it.